# php Prepared Statement giving me JSON Malformed

Tags: php, arrays, json, prepared-statement

My `php` code works fine when it is not a `prepared statement` - however when it is a prepared statement it is giving me a `json malformed error`. After debugging my code for some time I have realised that there is something wrong with my `if` statement and that it should be different when it is a `prepared statement`. I am not sure what to change but this is my code:

```
$statement = "SELECT userID, forename, surname, email, age FROM employees WHERE forename = ?"
$outcome = $conn -> prepare($statement);
$outcome->bind_param('s', $forename);
$outcome->execute();
$outcome->close();
$outcomearray = array();
echo json_encode("It works as of now"); // This bit works and the message is echoed

// From this point, it is giving me errors and problems
if(mysqli_num_rows($outcome)){
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($outcome)){
        $outcomearray[] = array
        (
            "userID" => $line["userID"],
            "forename" => $line["forename"],
            "surname" => $line["surname"],
            "username" => $line["username"],
            "email" => $line["email"],
            "age" => $line["age"]
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($outcomearray);
}
```

It is the following two lines:

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($outcome)){
        while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($outcome)){
```

that I believe are giving the errors.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you removed this `echo json_encode("It works as of now");` and tried again?

Comment: I have and I am getting `Malformed JSON: Unexpected '<'`. I believe it is the `if` statement

Comment: Close the connection at the end of your script instead of before fetching the rows.

Comment: What is the output of your script?

Comment: Malformed JSON: Unexpected '<' - it works fine when it is not a prepared statement

Comment: This is not the output. This is the **error** some parser throws. Run your script in a browser and see.

Comment: How do I do that? I am using `Postman`

Comment: `locahost/script.php` or whatever.

Comment: how do I provide the parameters then>

Comment: `$forename = 'VALUE HERE'`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
  "SELECT userID, forename, surname, email, age FROM employees WHERE forename = ?"
);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $forename);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = array();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($line = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $rows[] = $line;
}

print json_encode($rows);

$conn->close();
```

Note that this is the typical pattern when you are returning JSON resonses. If there is no match you render an empty array - thus there is no real need to check the number of rows.

If you for whatever reason needed to you can get the number of rows from the `num_rows` property on the `mysqli_result` object:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ((bool) $result->num_rows) {

}
```

Also note that the whole point of fetch_assoc is to get an associative array. So if your column names line up with the JSON you want to produce there is no need to map the keys one by one.

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: Sorry, for the mess and the many edits. Still waiting for the coffee to kick in...

Comment: Worked like a charm Max! Thank you for explaining it and as I am a fair man I have up voted and accepted your response.

Answer (score -1):

Try use

```
$outcome->num_rows;
```

OR

```
mysqli_stmt_num_rows($outcome);
```

Also use

```
$outcome->bind_result('userID','email', 'age', 'surname', 'forename');
$outcome->fetch()
```

instead

```
mysqli_assoc_fetch()
```

Comment: I edit my answer. Can you get information about error that you get.

Comment: `assoc_fetch` and `fetch` do very different things.

Comment: Also $outcome is the `mysqli_stmt`not the result object which is a pretty easy mistake to make since the variable naming is so wrong.